# CSS: what does a double-declaration do?

Tags: css, element

i'm building a custom theme for wordpress and saw this in the default 2010 style.css file:

```
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 940px;
}
#wrapper {
  background: pink;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

now this is the default code (except the `pink`).  when i try and collapse it, which seems logical, it makes quite a difference.

what i can't figure out is WHY you'd declare the same element twice like that?  i've never seen that before...

WR!

Answer (score 4):

It proves useful when you want to apply shared properties at multiple elements. Another useful application is adding stylesheets from multiple sources
 Example:

```
#head, #foot {
    height: 100px;
}
#foot { /*Another foot*/
    color: red;
}
```

Second example: CSS from multiple sources:

```
/* External stylesheet: common.css */
body {
    background: yellow;
}
/* Inline stylesheet, overrides external stylehseet */
body {
    background: pink;
}
```

When two properties have the same specificity, the lastly declared property will be applied.

Comment: this, i already know.  the above is from the SAME file, as i said.  actually READ the question instead of assuming it's something you've already seen please.

Comment: @WhiteRau These are some examples. There could be various reasons for having two IDs: `1. The developer added CSS without looking whether a selector already exists   2. The selectors were originally located at different files, but after merging the files, the selectors appeared twice   3. Originally, one of the #wrapped selectors were a part of #another,#wrapper. The developer decided to remove #another, and used search-and-replace on "#wrapper,?", resulting in two #wrapper selectors.` I have given another three examples. Do you have a better understanding now?

Comment: don't think i'm commmunicating what the issue is very effectively.  i'm abandoning this question.  i'm already -2 for my curiosity...  not worth it.  :P

Comment: I did +1, since I have seen worse questions. Did I understand your question well? (see answer + comment).

Comment: i'll have to check my cache or something.  i have only one CSS file and it's doing very strange things with this section of code.  i understand CSS very well (i thought) but i don't understand why i'm getting such different behavior when i collapse the declaration.  the margins spread out, the pink, which doesn't show when its as i typed it, suddenly does when its all under one element.  :'(  so based on what everyone's saying, its got to be a local issue.  which is unsettling because what ELSE is not working...?  *gack*

Comment: @WhiteRau Let's save you a headache. Get [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), and use the `Inspect element` feature. Using this, you will know the source of the declarations within a minute.

Comment: i'm already using Firebug... and it's pointing to this weird block of CSS.  *argh*

Comment: Can you post the HTML + CSS at a fiddle?

Comment: it's something local.  it doesn't duplicate on my laptop or @ fiddle.  dammit.  :(  thanks for your help, though.  i'll post what the glitch was once i find it...  arghh...

Answer (score 0):

It just overrides previously declared properties.

`wrapper` will now have `margin:20px auto 0 auto` (Top Right Bottom Left).

Comment: no.  it does something else. being WP and all, their code is usually pretty tight, so a double declaration didn't make sense.  also, as i stated, when you try and collapse the two together, something entirely different happens.  which, if all the second is doing is overriding the first, shouldn't happen.  nothing should happen.  but it does, for reasons i don't understand.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nAGxa/ - This is what I was talking about. If something else entirely is happening, there has to be something else somewhere in the CSS that is making it happen.

Comment: i'll investigate that.  we'll consider this closed.  can't afford the steady drop in points to keep trying to find an answer.  thanks.